# Retrieve specific items from list Sharepoint Online WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api

I try to get only specified values from list of sharepoint so my code is this:

```
 public List<MenuPrincipal> GetMenuOptions(string idioma)
        {
            List<MenuPrincipal> result = new List<MenuPrincipal>();
            try
            {
                SecureString pwd = SPAccess.GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(Definitions.UserPassword);

                using (var context = new ClientContext(Definitions.WebUrl))
                {
                    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Definitions.UserName, pwd);
                    List listResult = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MenuPrincipal");

                    //CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000);

                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Idioma'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>", idioma);
                    ListItemCollection items = listResult.GetItems(query);



                    context.Load(items);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (ListItem item in items)
                    {
                        result.Add(new MenuPrincipal
                        {
                            Titile = item["Title"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Title"].ToString(),
                            Enlace = item["Enlace"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Enlace"].ToString(),
                            Posicion = item["Posicion"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item["Posicion"]),
                            Idioma = item["Idioma"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Idioma"].ToString(),
                            Funcion = item["Funcion"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Funcion"].ToString()
                        });    
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return result.OrderBy(x => x.Posicion).ToList();
        }
```

But it gets alot of values, and I only need values that are in my foreach, so I try to do something like:

```
context.Load(
            items,
                lists => lists.Include( 
                list => list.Titile.
                list => list.Enlace,
                list => list.Posicion,
                list => list.Idioma,
                list => list.Funcion));
```

instead of `context.Load(items);`

But all my list is marked in red like photo:[image]

MSN [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538683(v=office.14).aspx)

Can anyone help me how to retrieve specific fields there? Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Title`, `Enlace` and other properties you tired to include are not defined on the `ListItem`, you can load properties like `Id` or `DisplayName` but to load custom fields you have to specify those same way you access those - with `[]` as on the snippet below

```
context.Load(
            items,
                columns => columns.Include( 
                i=> i["Title"],
                i=> i["Enlace"],
                i=> i["Posicion"],
                i=> i["Idioma"],
                i=> i["Funcion"]));
```